# Unable to merge actions producing... prerequisites are different

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

In Unreal Engine 4, I was working on some c++ files as part of a game dev project when I was told that I hadn't updated the project on my computer properly, and needed to get the current files from the source control onto my computer's instance of the project to keep working. This required overwriting the c++ files, so I backed up the c++ files I made and re-implemented them after getting my project updated. When all was said and done, I got errors I've never seen before:

`ERROR: Unable to merge actions producing AICharacter.cpp.obj: prerequisites are different`
`ERROR: Action graph is invalid; unable to continue. See log for details.`

I'm assuming this has something to do with my AICharacter source file, so I'll include it here:

````
#include "AICharacter.h"
#include "MainVillian.h"
#include "Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"

// Sets default values
AAICharacter::AAICharacter()
{
    // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
    
    //Init the box and audio comps
    BoxComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(FName("BoxComp"));
    BoxComp->AttachTo(GetRootComponent());

    AudioComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<UAudioComponent>(FName("AudioComp"));
    AudioComp->AttachTo(GetRootComponent());

}

void AAICharacter::OnBoxOverlap(AActor * OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent * OtherComp, int32 OtherIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult & SweepResult)
{
    if (OtherActor->IsA<AMainVillian>())
    {
        AMainVillian* Char = Cast<AGV_ProjectCharacter>(OtherActor);
        Char->SetTalkRangeStatus(true);
        Char->GeneratePlayerLines(*PlayerLines);
        Char->SetAssociatedPawn(this);
    }
}

void AMainVillian::OnBoxEndOverlap(AActor * OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent * OtherComp, int32 OtherIndex)
{
    if (OtherActor->IsA<AMainVillian>())
    {
        AMainVillian* Char = Cast<AMainVillian>(OtherActor);
        Char->SetTalkRangeStatus(false);
        Char->SetAssociatedPawn(nullptr);
    }
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AAICharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
 
    //Register the begin and end overlap functions
    BoxComp->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AAICharacter::OnBoxOverlapWrapper);
    BoxComp->OnComponentEndOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AAICharacter::OnBoxEndOverlapWrapper);
    
}

// Called every frame
void AAICharacter::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AAICharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

}

void AAICharacter::Talk(USoundBase* SFX, TArray<FSubtitle> Subs)
{
    AMainVillian* Char = Cast<AMainVillian>(UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerCharacter(GetWorld(), 0));

    //Play the corresponding sfx
    AudioComp->SetSound(SFX);
    AudioComp->Play();

    //Tell the UI to update with the new subtitles
    Char->GetUI()->UpdateSubtitles(Subs);
}

void AAICharacter::AnswerToCharacter(FName PlayerLine, TArray<FSubtitle>& SubtitlesToDisplay, float delay)
{
    if (!AILines) return;

    //Retrieve the corresponding line
    FString ContextString;
    FDialogStruct* DialogStruct = AILines->FindRow<FDialogStruct>(PlayerLine, ContextString);

    AMainVillian* MainChar = Cast<AMainVillian>(UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerCharacter(GetWorld(), 0));

    if (DialogStruct && MainChar)
    {
        FTimerHandle TimerHandle;
        FTimerDelegate TimerDel;

        TimerDel.BindUFunction(this, FName("Talk"), DialogStruct->SFX, DialogStruct->Subtitles);

        //Talk to the player after the delay time has passed
        GetWorld()->GetTimerManager().SetTimer(TimerHandle, TimerDel, delay, false);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Did you look at the log for details?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the *content* of the source file. Those errors look like source code control error messages. Seems you did something wrong when you performed that update.

Comment: Seems [this dude](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/897581/upgrading-from-ue420-to-ue4221-unable-to-merge-act.html?childToView=897584#answer-897584) got the error for having duplicated source files.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out based on George's answer: for some reason, every time I save AICharacter.cpp it saves to my 'Public' folder, when I wanted it to save to a folder within Public. Because of this, a duplicate was created every time I attempt to save it, and I needed to manually move the saved version to the folder I wanted it to be in and delete the older version.